# Converting Ints into binary / hex with ^ operator

Tags: python

I have two variables, Read and Out.

Read is a string e.g. "1101", Next there is Out which will be an int following the same binary format such as 100000 etc. I need to perform an operation so that If my two variables are

```
>>1000
>>1011
Output: 0011
```

I have tried to use Read ^ Out, I have tried to convert them to hex and do that but they always turn out as ints with other numbers ( 2-9 ). Output needs to be Int or a binary literal ( 0b0101 )

edit: This value is then sent off to another function like so    Write( 0x20, 0x13, Out ). Whenever it gets sent Python automatically converts it to an int if its a binary, which causes problems later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` works on ints.

You can convert strings to integers with a specified base:

> int(x=0) -> integer
>
> int(x, base=10) -> integer

For the opposite conversion there's [`bin()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#bin).

```
In [1]: bin(int('1000', 2) ^ int('1011', 2))
Out[1]: '0b11'
```

The rest is a matter of string formatting. If you want to always have it in four digits and without the prefix, take a look at [arshajii's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18613808/1258041).

Comment: Thanks, Didn't think to enclose it all in a bin() xD. Too tired, no coffee. Will accept it in 4 minutes... You are damn fast ;)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for a format operation in addition to `^`:

```
>>> a = int('1000', 2)
>>> b = int('1011', 2)
>>> format(a ^ b, '04b')
'0011'
```

Notice that `11` in binary is equal to `0011`:

```
>>> int('11', 2) == int('0011', 2)
True
```

It just comes down to how the number is represented as a string.

Comment: `format(a ^ b, '04b')` is an alternative - but mostly style I guess.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks; I like that one better.

Answer (score 1):

Use int() with a base of 2 to convert both variables:

```
>>> bin(int("1000", 2) ^ int(1011, 2))
>>> 0b11
```